# Hazelcast multinode discovery with tcp

Tags: hazelcast

We are looking into the multinode cluster for hazelcast using TCP mechanism. Say the first node has configuration as below
`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
</tcp-ip>`

and the second node has a configuration as below
`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <member>IP of first node (any one active node)</member>
</tcp-ip>`

The second node successfully gets added to the cluster and everything is fine. Now if the first node goes down and comes back online it becomes a separate cluster (single node) rather than getting added to existing cluster. I tried with configuration as below
`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
   <interface>Range of IP's (eg: xxx.xxx.xxx.100-120)</interface>
 </tcp-ip>`
for the first node but that works if the second node is online. But if its the first node then it never starts... I am not sure exactly how should the first node be setup such that it gets added to the cluster if already present or should be setup as a new cluster if no other members available. Or is it necessary that we have to edit the cluster.xml for the first node once it goes down?? Please help

Answer (score 4):

You need to add at least one IP address of an active member to join an existing cluster.

Please see; http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/#discovering-members-by-tcp